# How to change BlockReference display color?

Tags: eyeshot

When I loaded the drawing (AutoCAD *.dwg), many blocks display as white color so they are not good for readability. I dump their information and I see `Color = Color.Black` and `ColorMethod = ByLayer`. Which mean they should show in black but instead they show in white.  I try to `Explode()` then apply `Color.Black` but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the Block entities and change the color there.

Beware the `entity.ColorMethod` property controls where the color comes from:

1. `byEntity` uses the `entity.Color`.
2. `byLayer` uses the layer color (the layer is identified by the `entity.LayerName`)
3. `byParent` inherits the color of the BlockReference.